# indexOf match variable in this particular case

Tags: javascript, html, class, indexof

I want to check if `mydiv` have or don't have a *class*, if it don't have it, add whatever it is inside the *var* `newClass`. I am attempting to do it like this, but it is not working:

```
var newClass="classToBeAdded";

if(document.getElementById("mydiv").className.indexOf(/(?:^| )(newClass)(?:$| )/)==-1){
    document.getElementById("mydiv").className+=" "+newClass;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var newClass = "classToBeAdded";
var d = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var r = new RegExp(" " + newClass + " ");
if (r.test(" " + d.className + " "))
    // do something here
```

Or, similarly:

```
var d = document.getElementById("mydiv");
if ((" " + d.className + " ").indexOf(" " + newClass + " ") != -1)
    // do something here
```

The spaces are added before and after the `className` string so that we'll match the target class no matter where it appears in the string.

**Some tests**

Assume the following function:

```
function hasClass(str, name) {
    return (" " + str + " ").indexOf(" " + name + " ") != -1;
}
```

Tests:

```
hasClass("target", "target") // true
hasClass("test target test1", "target") // true
hasClass("test1 target", "target") // true
hasClass("target test1", "target") // true
hasClass("test1", "target") // false
```

Comment: will `" " + newClass + " "` check for first/last classes?

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess - Yes. Try it.

Comment: `"(^| )+" + newClass + "($| )+"` would do a trick (didn't try but presume it would)

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess - Added some tests to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript property of dom element

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").classList
```

it returns array of assigned class names

Comment: it don't work in older versions of browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: +1 I did not know about `classList`, but it needs newer browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList).

Comment: It is true, but there is always way to extend prototype of any kind to add property ;) but you should use jQuery or any similar to make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a library to abstract these kind of issues for you.

The rule of thumb is you should focus on your domain specific problems rather than re-inventing the wheel.

jQuery [.hassClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) is a good candidate